# Is there a Run extension method for IDbConnectionFactory in ServiceStack v4?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

This method exited in the OrmLiteConnectionFactoryExtensions class in v3.  Was it removed completely or just moved to another location?

Answer (score 0):

It was removed completely, as the normal way to open and use a db connection is more informative as to what is really going on, e.g:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
   db.Select(...);
```